# Reduce time of initializing a Pandas DataFrame in Python / increase performance of this operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have the following scenario : a backend application written in Python that reads from a Cassandra database, then it does some processing and then it sends the data to the front end.

The problem : the operation of initializing a Pandas DataFrame from a Python dict takes too long.

The code that is taking too long and causing some performance issues:

```
st = time.time()
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data_to_df)
print_statistics('orjson', '()', 'data_to_df_perf.py', time.time() - st)
```

In this case **data_to_df** is a list, containing around 70.000 entries like :

```
{"year": 2022, "month": 2, "quarter": 1, "value": 156.99, "day": 16, "hour": 0, "week": 7, "wk_year": 2022, "is_peak": 0}
{"year": 2022, "month": 2, "quarter": 1, "value": 155.38, "day": 16, "hour": 1, "week": 7, "wk_year": 2022, "is_peak": 0}
{"year": 2022, "month": 2, "quarter": 1, "value": 132.78, "day": 16, "hour": 2, "week": 7, "wk_year": 2022, "is_peak": 0}
...
```

The initial input is a **str** which gets passed as an input parameter to my function and then gets transformed into the list :

```
data = orjson.loads(orjson.loads(data))
data_to_df = data['data']

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data_to_df)
```

In my Python app, when it is deployed in AWS, the operation of transforming **data_to_df** takes between 1.5 seconds and 2 seconds and this causing a performance problem as this part of the code is called several times.

Output on localmachine :

```
<class 'list'
orjson () data_to_df_perf.py Execution time: 0.13002800941467285156 s
```

Does anyone know how to reduce this costly operation ?

Anyone has something different in mind ? Like transforming the list to another data type and then initializing the Pandas DataFrame ?

DataFrame constructor says :

> Parameters
> ----------
> data : ndarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or DataFrame
> Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, dataclass or list-like objects. If
> data is a dict, column order follows insertion-order. If a dict contains Series
> which have an index defined, it is aligned by its index.

Other things that I tried :

```
st = time.time()
data = pd.read_csv('tests/HPFC_power_data_to_df_2.txt', header = None)
print_statistics('from file', '()', 'test_data_to_df_perf.py', time.time() - st)


st = time.time()
data = dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_to_df)
print_statistics('records', '()', 'test_data_to_df_perf.py', time.time() - st)


st = time.time()
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data_to_df)
print_statistics('default', '()', 'test_data_to_df_perf.py', time.time() - st)

st = time.time()
df = pd.read_json(json_data_list, orient ='records')
print_statistics('records', '()', 'test_data_to_df_perf.py', time.time() - st)
```

Output :

```
from file () test_data_to_df_perf.py execution 0.10300374031066894531
records () test_data_to_df_perf.py execution 0.11999869346618652344
default () test_data_to_df_perf.py execution 0.11696839332580566406
records () test_data_to_df_perf.py execution 0.26199913024902343750
```

Thanks !

Comment: does it has to be a pandas.DataFrame object or could you also go with the list of dictionaries? What happens with the table? could you move some operations before converting the data to a table, so that less data is converted?

Comment: The thing is it's quite hard now, at this moment in time, to replace pandas, as I have more than 700 calls to other pandas objects and operations. This is why I identified these 2 operations which are very time consuming and take a lot of memory. For example, afterwards I do different indexed joins (previously it was merges, but it was quite expensive in terms of time) and so on.